# Not finding getresource in BitmapFactory.decodeResource inside ViewHolder in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Use for rounding the image but not getting getresources method due to recyclerview adapter inheritence.
Not finding getresources in BitmapFactory.decodeResource

```
CODE--
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //ImageView image;
    TextView imageName;
    RelativeLayout parent_layout;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
        parent_layout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getresources,R.drawable.ic_svg_profile);
        roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
        ImageView imgvw = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imgvw.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(itemView.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_svg_profile);`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!!!!!. Can you tell me what's happening here?

Comment: [BitmapFactory.decodeResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)) requires resources object and resource id of the image data. You can usually get resources with a command [getResources()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getResources()), but as you are using it in ViewHolder, you need to pass a context first (and that's why we use the View(in this case **itemView** ).getContext())